# They're all OURS (GHI)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I'm looking for a two-word phrase.

---

```
      EAT       (NOP)
      CON       (JKL)
      NOW       (TUV)
      NOW       (TUV)
      CON       (JKL)
      ICE       (OPQ)
      EAR       (HIJ)
      END       (MNO)
      PIC       (FGH)
      ALE       (UVW)
      ALE       (UVW)
      PIC       (FGH)
      AGE       (STU)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two-word phrase is:

> **MISSING LETTER**

All of the triplets in the left-hand column are actually:

> **four-letter words missing their initial letter**. That missing initial letter is also the one which precedes the three alphabetically consecutive letters that appear in parentheses in the right-hand column.
>
>  So the first line is missing the 'M' for **M**EAT (with the alphabetical sequence **M**NOP...), the second is missing the 'I' for **I**CON (**I**JKL), and other letters that appear here are the 'S' for **S**NOW (**S**TUV), 'N' for **N**ICE (**N**OPQ), 'G' for **G**EAR (**G**HIJ), 'L' for **L**END (**L**MNO), 'E' for **E**PIC (**E**FGH), 'T' for **T**ALE (**T**UVW), and 'R' for **R**AGE (**R**STU).
>
>  Read downwards, these initials spell **MISSING LETTER**.

As for the title:

> this conforms to the same rule, revealing that 'They're all **F**OURS (**F**GHI), implying that all the 'three-letter' words here are actually concealed **four**-letter words!

Comment: Quick. Well done!